# data.table join using two columns from one table and one column from other

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables, lets call them `weights` and `values`.
The `weights` table has 5 columns as follows:

```
first POSIXct
late POSIXct
nodeid integer
aggid integer
weight numeric
```

The `values` table has these columns

```
nodeid integer
Date POSIXct
hour integer
value decimal
```

The idea is to generate a new table where it will take the weighted average of the nodes into aggregate nodes based on the weightings.  However, the weightings change through time and need to be matched based on the first and late date.  SQL syntax to do this would look something like this

```
select v.Date, v.hour, w.aggid, sum(v.value*w.weight) as aggvalue
from values v inner join weights w
on v.nodeid=w.nodeid and v.date between w.first and w.late
group by aggid, date, hour
```

I'm not really sure where to start on this one given the `between` logic in the SQL syntax.  Is this possible in data.table syntax or would I need to transform the `weights` table to have a row for every single day as opposed to using the range?

Here is some example data (sorry it's so long)...

```
values<-data.table(nodeid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Date = c("2013-07-02", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-05", 
"2013-07-08", "2013-07-10", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-05", 
"2013-07-08", "2013-07-10", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-05", 
"2013-07-08", "2013-07-10", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-05", 
"2013-07-08", "2013-07-10", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-05", 
"2013-07-08", "2013-07-10", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-05", 
"2013-07-08", "2013-07-10"), hour = c(1L, 2L, 23L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 23L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 23L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 23L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 23L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 23L, 2L, 2L), value = c(8.234, 3.218, 
0.787, 8.689, 6.218, 6.89, 1.914, 2.459, 6.683, 8.122, 0.281, 
1.136, 1.993, 7.27, 9.582, 5.777, 1.375, 9.204, 7.862, 0.633, 
2.433, 1.842, 7.178, 10.692, 1.417, 1.259, 2.619, 0.031, 6.744, 
5.941))

weights<-data.table(first = c("2013-07-01", "2013-07-01", "2013-07-01", 
"2013-07-01", "2013-07-01", "2013-07-01", "2013-07-08", "2013-07-08", 
"2013-07-08", "2013-07-08", "2013-07-08", "2013-07-08"), late = c("2013-07-07", 
"2013-07-07", "2013-07-07", "2013-07-07", "2013-07-07", "2013-07-07", 
"2013-07-20", "2013-07-20", "2013-07-20", "2013-07-20", "2013-07-20", 
"2013-07-20"), nodeid = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L), aggid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), weight = c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.45, 0.15))

exresults<-data.table(aggid = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), Date = c("2013-07-02", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-02", 
"2013-07-05", "2013-07-05", "2013-07-08", "2013-07-08", "2013-07-10", 
"2013-07-10"), hour = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 23L, 23L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), aggvalue = c(5.90975, 3.2014, 2.3715, 1.8573, 1.5065, 6.3564, 
8.004, 8.9678, 7.2716, 1.782))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `roll` param of `data.table` joins:

```
setkey(values, nodeid, Date)
setkey(weights, nodeid, late)

weights[values, roll = -Inf][, list(aggvalue = sum(weight*value)),
                               by = list(aggid, Date = late, hour)]
#    aggid       Date hour aggvalue
# 1:     1 2013-07-02    1  5.90975
# 2:     1 2013-07-02    2  2.37150
# 3:     1 2013-07-05   23  1.50650
# 4:     1 2013-07-08    2  8.00400
# 5:     1 2013-07-10    2  7.27160
# 6:     2 2013-07-02    1  3.20140
# 7:     2 2013-07-02    2  1.85730
# 8:     2 2013-07-05   23  6.35640
# 9:     2 2013-07-08    2  8.96780
#10:     2 2013-07-10    2  1.78200
```

Note: I'd be careful if the correct range doesn't exist - I didn't test that edge case.

Comment: I see you didn't need the `first` column and admittedly I need to do more reading on `roll` but is there a way to use `first` instead of `late`.  The way my real data is sourced, I just have the `first` date and I have to create the `late` column to create the ranges.  If there's a syntax that would allow me to only use the `first` column then I could skip creating the `late` column entirely.  Is that possible or is it a necessary step?

Comment: I changed the key on `weights` to `first` instead of `late` and changed `roll=-Inf` to `roll=Inf` and that appears to work.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor yep, that's exactly it